# Consulta con fecha mysql

Tags: mysql

Tengo en una tabla con un campo de tipo `TIMESTAMP`, quiero realizar una consulta de agrupación para registro del mismo día, sin tomar en cuenta la hora. Hay alguna función de `MYSQL` para ese tipo de dato que haga esto?

Answer (score 1):

Primero, se extrae la fecha con la función [`DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date), para quedarnos sólo con la fecha (sin la hora), y luego podemos agrupar con [`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) según ese valor. Entonces, [`COUNT(*)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html) nos va a devolver la cantidad de filas por día.

```sql
SELECT
    COUNT(*) as cuantos,
    DATE(cuando) as dia
FROM `tu_tabla`
GROUP BY dia
```

[Documentacion del uso de fechas y tiempo de Mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date)

Comment: Si bien esta respuesta puede dar solución al problema, no es bueno poner solo código. Es mejor que este se acompañe con una explicación, aunque sea breve.

Comment: @GustavoGarcía así esta bien? no sabría que mas agregar.

Comment: Sí, así está bien.